# Did I arrive at this answer using sound reasoning or was it a fluke?

Tags: geometry

[image]

Because E is the midpoint of AB and F is the midpoint of CD, I just added (25-12) to 25 to calculate that AD = 38. And because G is the midpoint AE and H is the midpoint of FD, I just subtracted (13/2) from 38 to calculate that GH = 31.5. This is the correct answer, but I'm not sure if I used sound reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sound, but needs some justification.  It is true that the length of chords parallel to BC or AD in your trapezoid are a linear function of the length from B to the endpoint or of the length from C to the endpoint.  You can justify this by extending AB and DC until they meet at point Z.  All the triangles with one vertex at Z and with the opposite side parallel to BC or AD are similar.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning is basically sound.  To help see this, try adding lines perpendicular lines from G, E, B, C, F and H to AD, say at points I, J, K, L, M and N.  Now, due to the various lines which are parallel, the triangles AGI, AEJ and ABK are similar to each other, and the triangles CLD, FMD and HND are also similar to each other.  You can then use the various midpoint values to determine the appropriate ratios of the various triangle side lines to each other and then use this to confirm what you determined.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.